# Setup subdomain to point to a specific directory using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I want to point the sub domain to different paths using .htacces
sub.domain.co.uk point to server path /htdocs_sub/
www.domain.co.uk point to server path /htdocs_www/

I'm trying:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.co\.uk$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/htdocs_sub/

RewriteRule (.*) /htdocs_sub/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.uk$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/htdocs_www/

RewriteRule (.*) /htdocs_www/$1

</IfModule>
```

doesn't respond correctly, just:

```
"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z\d]+)\.domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/htdocs_
RewriteRule . /htdocs_%1%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

assumed all paths are relative to the document root